# Hunchentoot 1.0 returns only empty responses

Tags: macos, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, hunchentoot

I'm using an Intel Mac with Mac OS 10.5 and SBCL 1.0.29.  I've done pre-1.0 Hunchentoot development here before, so I've had that installed (via asdf-install).

Recently I started a new project, and decided I'd start from Hunchentoot 1.0.  I asdf-install'ed Hunchentoot, and it seemed to install 1.0 (and deps) just fine.  I can load it in SBCL (via SLIME or Terminal), and I can write code against the new interface, and it compiles great, and everything seems fine.

That is, until I try to access the webpage: I only get empty responses.  Firebug reports "200 OK" but Page Info shows size "0 bytes" (text/plain, ISO-8859-1, but I'm guessing those are defaults).  So I tried netcat and telnet, and it seems to accept a connection on my port and then immediately disconnect.

Is there a problem with Hunchentoot 1.0 on Mac OS?  Or with having 2 Hunchentoot versions asdf-install'ed at the same time?  Or something else I'm not thinking of?  I'm sure it's probably something obvious but I'm drawing a blank here.

Thanks!

Comment: I would propose to ask this question on the Hunchentoot mailing list.

Comment: Have you checked this issue with a different Lisp interpreter? Here is a similar issue described (There it was a bug in CCL) http://sean-ross.blogspot.com/2009/03/hunchentoot-ccl-and-windows.html

Comment: Not yet, but that link is for both a different compiler and a different operating system, and so (unsurprisingly) the workaround suggested does not help me here.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a tutorial on how to write a Lisp webapp that includes a known working set of dependencies (including Hunchentoot, CFFI, etc).

You might want to check out the [documentation](http://blog.postabon.com/a-simple-lisp-webapp-for-beginners). Try running the code from the linked github page and see if it works for you - if it doesn't then the problem is in your Lisp Compiler (not your libraries). I'd link directly to github, but I'm new here, and apparently I don't have enough reputation points to post two links in one answer.

Off the top of my heads, I know SBCL has trouble with threads on Mac OS X. I'd consider looking into Clozure Common Lisp - which is very optimized for Macs.

Comment: I know SBCL threading on Darwin is considered experimental, but is there any specific "trouble" you're referring to?  I've been developing Lisp web apps with pre-1.0 Hunchentoot on SBCL (with threading enabled) here for over a year, and never once had a problem with it.

Comment: BTW, I downloaded your app and it runs fine.  So while SBCL may have issues, I'm seeing 100% failure with the asdf-installed Hunchentoot 1.0 and 100% success with the in-its-own-folder Hunchentoot 1.0, with the same SBCL, which suggests to me that my SBCL is not at fault here.

Comment: Well, about 1-2 years ago threading was seriously broken on Darwin (mutexes didn't work, the Lisp core would get corrupted, etc). Things may have gotten better since, but I was a little soured on the experience.

The fact that my app works proves pretty conclusively (in my mind) that it's probably just a bug in the ASDF version of Hunchentoot (or usocket?) that you're using - and not SBCL itself. The versions of libraries that are asdf-install'able are sometimes just out of date - which is why I avoid asdf-install (but not asdf, of course) and use the latest version of code from the author.